# Как узнать requests headers через python

Tags: python, requests, steam

Мне нужно отправить запрос на страницу с предметом из стим и получить его историю цен в рублях, для этого в headers нужно указать куки, которые обновляются каждый день

https://ibb.co/n1J7KSN

Есть ли возможность получать куки каждый день автоматически или как то создавать их самостоятельно?

Comment: Создайте у `requests` объект класса `Session` и через него делайте все запросы - он куки, полученные в ответе от сервера, будет хранить и передавать при ваших последующих запросах ([пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/db5eea01131df8e98248a0adf2cf133d193f0f39/html_parsing/emojipedia_org__search.py#L13))

Comment: куки меняются каждый день, а session хранит куки, мне же нужно автоматически обновлять их каждый день

Comment: Каждый день отправляйте запрос на сайт, эмулируя деятельность, сайт будет отдавать новые куки. Куки сайтом создаются, поэтому нужно с ним работать